# ffmpeg windows and linux version: Operation not permitted on linux

Tags: ffmpeg

I run the latest compiled ffmpeg versions from : http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/

This command works as it should on Windows:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://myIpAddress/live/video live=1" -c copy dump.flv
```

When I run it on Linux (ffmpeg got from http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/)

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://myIpAddress/live/video live=1" -c copy dump.flv
```

I got:

```
ffmpeg version N-46124-gb399816 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
built on Oct 29 2012 05:22:17 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)

configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52.  1.100 / 52.  1.100
  libavcodec     54. 69.100 / 54. 69.100
  libavformat    54. 35.100 / 54. 35.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 20.106 /  3. 20.106
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 16.100 /  0. 16.100
  libpostproc    52.  1.100 / 52.  1.100
[rtmp @ 0x37bde40] Server error: 
rtmp://myIPAddress/live/video live=1: Operation not permitted
```

Any idea ?

Comment: try using sudo for same command

Comment: Same. I am of course logged as ROOT.

Other ffmpeg commands work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your Linux version has not been compiled with librtmp. Notice carefully output from my version.

```
ffmpeg version N-47062-g26c531c Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 25 2012 12:25:21 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-pthreads --enable-runt
ime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libass -
-enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enab
le-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libo
pus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheo
ra --enable-libutvideo --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-li
bvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --ena
ble-zlib
```